# update value of global variable inside requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to update a global value inside of a request Animation frame function and get the updated value out. how do I do this

```
var flyPos;

function drawFrame() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
 transX = Math.sin(angleX) * range;
 transY = Math.sin(angleY) * range;
 fly.style.transform = `translate3d(${transX}px,${transY}px,0)`
 angleX += xspeed;
 angleY += yspeed;
 flyPos = fly.getBoundingClientRect();
 return flyPos;
```

/* i think this is scoping issue*/
}

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

console.log(flyPos);
```

this should look the position of the fly each time the animation frame runs

Comment: is the problem that the console.log statment logs out `undefined`?

Comment: hi @NicholasTower , yes it says that

Comment: It's not a scoping issue. It's a timing issue. `flyPos` is not going to be set until `rAF` runs its callback, which is going to be **after** your `console.log`. if you want to log the position of the fly each time `rAF` runs, then put the `console.log` inside the callback. Of course, as your code now stands, the callback will run only once.

Comment: So your code defines a variable flyPos (which is initialized to undefined), then it defines a function drawFrame, then it tells the browser "hey, could you run drawFrame for me in a little while?", then your code logs out flyPos, which is still undefined. Now your code is done. A short time later, the browser calls your drawFrame function. If you want the console.log to happen at the end of drawFrame, then move it inside drawFrame.

Comment: You aren't crazy, JavaScript has function scope and you are avoiding that scoping issue with your `var flyPos` in the upper scope, so nice work there. I think torazaburo is correct. What if you put the console log right before `return flyPos`, will this give you the data you need?

Comment: Yes , thank you i'm doing something else with the updated position but i'm going to try and work this out before i ask.

Comment: If i had a nickel for every time JavaScript dominated me with async timing related issues :) This is super super common because it throws stuff into the callstack or function queue and then immediately parses the next line of code like 1 millisecond later.

Comment: I just had a janky idea. We could just log the value of flyPos every 100ms? `setInterval(() => { console.log(flyPos) }, 100)` Could be useful for debugging it if all you want to do is get a reading on its behaviour.

Comment: @agm1984 1 millisecond => a few dozen nanoseconds.

Comment: Just watchout for that function queue, you can only store 56,000 pending functions at the same time :) or 65,000, one of the two. Your computer may detonate, but you will definitely see some values.

Comment: @torazaburo This is what i'm trying to do https://codepen.io/o-sewell/pen/mBOPzR?editors=0010 , when the mouse position collides with the fly i want it to display a message. please could anyone help. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /* i think this is scoping issue*/

It's not a scoping issue. It's a timing issue. `flyPos` is not going to be set until the callback you pass to `rAF` runs, which is going to be **after** your `console.log`.

If you want to log the position of the fly each time the `rAF` callback runs, then put the `console.log` inside the callback.